# Ext4.1 Accordion Layout--the width of accordion item is not enough

Tags: extjs, ext4

The accordion item is short when the component first rendered.Any good ideas?

I am using chrome browser.It seemed to be ok with IE9.

This is the url of jsfiddle test: http://jsfiddle.net/xgsZ7/2/. (Maybe the jsfiddle test need to fresh one more time to see the problem)

This is the test code:
Just a viewport and a panel with accordion layout rendered.

```
<html >
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script language="javascript">
    function createAccordion() {
        var item1 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
          title: 'Accordion Item 1',
          html: '&lt;empty panel&gt;',
          cls:'empty'
        });

        var accordion = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
          title: 'Accordion',
          collapsible: true,
          margins:'5 0 5 5',
          region:'west',
          split: true,
          width: 210,
          layout:'accordion',
          items: [item1]
        });
        return accordion;
   }

function createBody() {
    var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
      layout:'border',
      items:[
          createAccordion()
      ]
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>    
        createBody();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good test case. I've tried some things with the fiddle but the problem still remains. Btw a border layout always needs a center item.

Answer (score 0):

Do the render things by using Ext.onready will solve this problem.(http://jsfiddle.net/xgsZ7/3/)

```
<script>       
Ext.onReady(function() {
    createBody();
});
</script>
```

Comment: -1. A border layout requires a center region. Also, your code isn't wrapped in an onReady block, you need to wait til the DOM is ready before writing it.